# How to transfer data with multiple conditions with pgsql?

Tags: regex, postgresql, if-statement, sql-insert

I would like to create a trigger with I can check the uploaded data and I can insert into another table as well. In the initial table (capture) I have 15 columns, but I would like to transfer only 5 columns (ring_number, code, year, date, species, location) to another table (ring).

The **ring** table is a background table in which I am collecting the combinations of *ring_number* and *code*, more specifically one *ring_number* could be paired only with one *code*. There is one exception, when the *code* include "X", than it can be changed later, and in this case this *code* can be paired with more *ring_number*, and if originally belongs to the *ring_number* a *code* with "X" it can be changed later.

In the capture table, could be possible to upload the same combination of *code* and *ring_number* multiple times with a condition of a third column. But still the *ring_number* can be paired only with one *code*, with exceptions of *codes* included "X". The name of the conditional column is **recapture**. If **recapture** (boolean column type) is "true", then you can upload the combination of **code** and **ring_number** again. If it is "empty" or "no" you can upload only new combinations of **code** and **ring_number**. If somebody uploads old combinations then the following error message has to raise: this combination already exists, please check your data and if it is a recapture, then set the **recapture** column to yes.

Additionally: **ring_number** is a not null column, but **code** can be empty. And different **ring_number** can be paired with empty **code** than later can be paired with actual value.

I have several problems with my code:

1: I would like to define the exception to X with regex, and the X can be anywhere in the code. But can not manage the regex in a good way. It does just not work.

2: I write conditional checkpoint with **recapture** column and if I have an old combination this is work on the right way and say please set the **recapture** column to yes. But! If I set the **recapture** column to yes I get the same error message.

Could you help to solve these issues?

Here is my code:

```
Declare

  a   integer := 0;
  b   integer := 0;
  c   integer := 0;
  d   integer := 0;

Begin

  IF new.code <> '' THEN

    --Az 'a' means whether the given ring_number already exist in the database with a code, which is not empty
    SELECT INTO a COUNT(*) FROM plover_captures PC WHERE PC.ring_number = new.ring_number AND PC.code <> new.code AND PC.code <> '' AND PC.code ~ '[X]{2}[\.]{1}[X]{2}[|]{1}[X]{2}[\.]{1}[X]{2}';

    --Az 'b' means the given code already exist in the database with a ring_number
    SELECT INTO b COUNT(*) FROM plover_captures PC WHERE PC.ring_number <> new.ring_number AND PC.code = new.code AND PC.code ~ '[X]{2}[\.]{1}[X]{2}[|]{1}[X]{2}[\.]{1}[X]{2}';

    --Az 'c' how much times exist the given ring_number with the given code in the database
    SELECT INTO c COUNT(*) FROM plover_captures PC WHERE PC.ring_number = new.ring_number AND PC.code = new.code AND PC.code ~ '[X]{2}[\.]{1}[X]{2}[|]{1}[X]{2}[\.]{1}[X]{2}';

    --Az 'd' means the given combination already exist in ring table or not
    SELECT INTO d COUNT(*) FROM plover_rings PC WHERE PC.ring_number = new.ring_number AND PC.code = new.code; 

    IF a > 0 THEN
      raise exception 'This ring_number is already paired with another code before. %', new.ring_number;
    END IF;

    IF b > 0 THEN
      raise exception 'This code is already paired with another ring_number before. %', new.code;
    END IF;

    IF c > 0 AND (new.rettrap IS null OR new.rettrap IS false) THEN
      raise exception 'This ring_number and code pair is already in the database. So it is a rettrap but the rettrap attribute set to false or null. %, %, %', new.ring_number, new.code, new.rettrap;
    END IF;

    IF c = 0 AND new.rettrap IS true THEN
      raise exception 'The rettrap attribute set to true but this ring_number and code pair is not in this database yet. %, %, %', new.ring_number, new.code, new.rettrap;
    END IF;

    IF c = 0 AND d = 0 THEN
      Insert into plover_rings values(new.ring_number,new.code,new.species,new.location,new.year, new.date);
    END IF;

  END IF;

  Return new;

End
```

Comment: Why do you need regex instead of just `LIKE %X%`?

Comment: Shorter and more readable: `a := count(*) from ...`

Comment: @Jeremy thx a lot for this advice it was really helpful! I am new with SQL, and my first idea was regex.

Comment: @Abelisto thx a lot for you suggestion. If you mean that just delate declare part before begin and use the suggested format, it is unfortunately not working. Without deleting declare it is work, and indeed more readable! Thx for this suggestion again.